# PDO update column based on its current value not working

Tags: sql, pdo

I have this PDO statement:

```
parent::$db->custom('UPDATE users_credits SET availabe = availabe - :reward_credits, used = used + :reward_credits WHERE user_id = :user_id', array(
    'reward_credits' => $reward_credits,
    'user_id' => $user_id
));
```

For some reasons it simply does not work. I tried the very same query on the DB manually and it works.
What's wrong with PDO and how do I achieve the very same result I would achieve normally?

Thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

First of all. **There is nothing wrong with PDO** and never has been.
It is some **your own** custom code to blame.

Simple checklist to solve any PDO related problem

1. Make sure you can see all the PHP errors.
2. Configure PDO to throw exceptions in SQL errors, by calling this after connect

   ```
   $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   ```
3. Debug your code.

Comment: I did not mean to say PDO is wrong, I meant what's wrong with my PDO statement. Anyway I found the issue. It simply was a wrong character in the query. Thanks anyway

Comment: Dunno what you mean but you asked "What's wrong with PDO". Wrong character in the query have to be reported via exception I told you of.